# How to Place exported files in Secure File Transfer Protocol(SFTP) location using Mysql Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, authentication, stored-procedures, sftp, private-key

Is it possible to create a Stored Procedure in MySQL to read values from some tables and dump the data set in `.csv` or `.txt` file to some Secure File Transfer Protocol locations using the `.ppk` (PuTTY Private Key) file for authentication. If yes, what are the steps to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that in MySQL. Two feature to access a filesystem, the [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) syntax and the [LOAD_FILE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) function, are both readonly and both limited to files that are *local to either the server or the client machine*. The MySQL server cannot directly access filesystems hosted by other servers.

Comment: Is there any option of doing it.? 
Can we do it in other databases like Oracle using Stored Procedures ?

Comment: Sure, you can do that but not directly from a MySQL server, e.g. not from a trigger. What you could do for e.g. is to write a simple shell script. From a Bash shell, you can connect any remote host and read/write to them (with appropriate privileges, of course). So the script could connect to the first server, read some data, store it temporarily in a variable then connect to another server and make an insert statement.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you please share a small example to achieve this.